# Write default array to variable in Bash

Tags: bash, array

I was expecting

```
excludes="${excludes:-( ${default_excludes[@]} )}"
```

to be an array if `$excludes` is empty. Unfortunately the stuff after `:-` is taken to be a string. Did I miss some syntax contortion, or do I have to use the clunky

```
if [ -z "${excludes:-}" ]
then
    excludes=( "${default_excludes[@]}" )
fi
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can construct an array from another array with this syntax:

```
arr1=( "${arr2[@]}" )
```

That can be translated into this default-value syntax:

```
arr1=("${arr1[@]:-${arr2[@]}}")
```

I've tested some edge cases, like array members with spaces or newlines in them and it seems to handle them correctly.

Comment: If arr2 is an empty, arr1 becomes an array of length one with one empty string

Comment: if you need to use this in combo with incoming script parameters, use: `main_args=( "${@:-${default_args[@]}}")` Note the lack of brackets on the first`@`

Answer (score 2):

Since I had cases where my `arr2` might be empty, but set, I could not find a simple solution. So I had to go with a function and global temp variable. But it works in every case and in bash 3.2 and bash 4

```
function set_temp_array()
{ # 1 - source_array_name $2-* default_values
  local default="$1"
  shift
  if declare -p $default >& /dev/null; then
    default="${default}[@]"
    TEMP_VAR=("${!default}")
  else
    TEMP_VAR=("${@}")
  fi
}

set_temp_array arr1 "${arr2[@]}"
arr1="${TEMP_VAR[@]}"
```

I use indirect array reference to copy the values to `TEMP_VAR`, but I couldn't figure out an indirect array assignment in bash, hence the two lines and temp variable

For you `set -eu` fans out there

```
function set_temp_array()
{ # 1 - source_array_name $2-* default_values
  local default="$1"
  shift
  if declare -p $default >& /dev/null; then
    default="${default}[@]"
    TEMP_VAR=(${!default+"${!default}"})
  else
    TEMP_VAR=(${@+"${@}"})
  fi
}

set_temp_array arr1 ${arr2+"${arr2[@]}"}
arr1=(${TEMP_VAR+"${TEMP_VAR[@]}"})
```