# Can you assign a default array to a variable by specifying its values explicitly?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I know that I can use an existing array as the default value for a variable that is potentially uninitialized via

```bash
default_values=(1 2 'value is a string')
array=("${array[@]-${default_values[@]}}")
```

as already answered in, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195979/556459.

What I want to know instead is if I can assign such a default array to a variable by specifying its values explicitly instead of introducing a helper array such as `default_values`?

The fact that assigning an array to a variable via `array=(value1 ...)` is called a compound assignment by the [Bash Reference Manual for Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) strongly suggests that it is special syntax and that I cannot simply create array literals by using the `(value1 ...)` syntax for the value to be substituted in a shell parameter expansion. While trying that indeed fails, maybe there is some alternative that I have missed?

Comment: nhh, I think `${array-...}` there  is the same as `${array[0]-...}` (as usual), and only tests one element of the array. If the array is sparse, it can trash existing values. Anyway, relying on `[@]` working properly on the right side of `${var-value}` also seems like something I wouldn't want to count on... Why not just `if [ "${#array[@]}" = 0 ]; then array=(some default values); fi` ?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot the `[@]` in my above example. I'll edit my question shortly to correct that. (It's there in the linked answer though.) I'm aware that using as imply if-statement would be an option (just like using a separate variable) but it would be "neater" if I could get this to work using some form of shell expansion instead.

Comment: Question is updated and in my previous comment "using as imply if-statement" was supposed to read "using a simple if-statement", but I cannot edit a comment after five minutes.